# Why this query (Mysql) doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query (Mysql)

```
$query_Search = 'SELECT ID, Titre , Categorie, Description, Province , Com_Territ, Type_Annonce, Prix, Devise, Date, State
                              FROM articles
                              WHERE  Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' OR Categorie LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\'
                              ORDER BY CASE WHEN Titre LIKE \'' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' THEN 0 
                              WHEN Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '\' THEN 1 
                              ELSE 2 END';
```

I want to add a condition in WHERE clause, my condition is (WHERE State='3') and i do it like this:

```
$query_Search = 'SELECT ID, Titre , Categorie, Description, Province , Com_Territ, Type_Annonce, Prix, Devise, Date, State
                              FROM articles
                              WHERE State='3' AND Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' OR Categorie LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\'
                              ORDER BY CASE WHEN Titre LIKE \'' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' THEN 0 
                              WHEN Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '\' THEN 1 
                              ELSE 2 END';
```

this query displays some results whith States not equal to 3, seems like it doesn't care about the condition (WHERE State='3')

Comment: Well.. you have got a few `OR`s in there too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `OR` in your `WHERE` statement so it can be that you get columns that have `State = 3` OR! something else.
Add some `(` and `)` to group your statement like:

```
WHERE State='3' AND (Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' OR Categorie LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\')
```

Comment: Thanks,
Was a rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just like putvande mentioned above, try this:

```
$query_Search = 'SELECT ID, Titre , Categorie, Description, Province , Com_Territ, Type_Annonce, Prix, Devise, Date, State
                          FROM articles
                          WHERE State='3' AND (Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' OR Categorie LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' )
                          ORDER BY CASE WHEN Titre LIKE \'' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '%\' THEN 0 
                          WHEN Titre LIKE \'%' . safe( $_POST['q'] ) . '\' THEN 1 
                          ELSE 2 END';
```